# gson error: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 166

Tags: java, json, gson

I have following class `SolrFBLocationDoc`:

```
public class SolrFBLocationDoc{

    @Field
    private String name;
    @Field
    private String id;
    @Field
    private Location location = new Location();

    //and some more class members
}
```

where, `Location` is a class from restfb: `com.restfb.types.Location`.

I'm trying to convert a `solrDocument` to an object of class `SolrFBLocationDoc` as given below:

```
SolrFBLocationDoc doc = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(solrDoc), SolrFBLocationDoc.class);
```

where, `solrDoc` is:

```
SolrDocument[{id=106377336067638, location=Location[city=null country=null latitude=null longitude=null state=null street=null zip=null]}]
```

and `gson.toJson(solrDoc)` returns,

```
{"id":"106377336067638","location":"Location[city\u003dnull country\u003dnull latitude\u003dnull longitude\u003dnull state\u003dnull street\u003dnull zip\u003dnull]"}
```

But, it's resulting into the error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 166
```

I can see the problem is occuring due to conversion of `Location` class object to String by `gson.toJson(solrDoc)`.

Then without using `gson.toJson(solrDoc)`, how can I convert `SolrDocument` to `SolrFBLocationDoc`?

How can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your `SolrFBLocationDoc` class, `location` ivar is of kind `com.restfb.types.Location` but into your JSON string:

```
"location":"Location[city\u003dnull country\u003dnull latitude\u003dnull longitude\u003dnull state\u003dnull street\u003dnull zip\u003dnull]"
```

means that `location` is a string. Due to `SolrFBLocationDoc` definition, indeed, after semicolon, Gson expects a "{" (that is a `BEGIN_OBJECT`). But it finds `"Location..`, that is a string, so it won't parse.

Right string would be like:

```
{"id":"106377336067638","location":{"city":null, "country":null, "latitude":null, "longitude":null, "state":null, "street":null, "zip":null}}
```

So this means that `gson.toJson(solrDoc)` returns you a escaped string for `location` key. This could depends on how `SolrDocument` is defined. Probably in that class `location` field is a string. If you could put definition of `SolrDocument`, this answer can be refined and hypothesis confirmed/rejected.